# Running a script over multiple spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a "template spreadsheet" to manage our clients. For each new client, we have to duplicate the template spreadsheet. The spreadsheet uses scripts, and each time we duplicate it each user (my employees) has to authorize access to the scripts again.

This is not a huge problem, but I'd like to know if there is a way to make it more user friendly. Basically, "separating" the script from the master spreadsheet so as when the spreadsheet is duplicated the script file will be the same and users won't have to authorize it again.

Other benefit: if i need to improve or fix the scripts, the update will affect all the spreadsheets at once.

Is the solution deploying the script as a web-app? I don't anything about that
(I use Gsuite).

Thank you!

Comment: An add-on can be created, and deployed inside of the GSuite account just for the organization.  All spreadsheets would show the add-on in the add-ons menu.  I wouldn't say that creating an add-on is easy, but it would avoid the constant need to authorize every script.  Because the add-on would be published within the organization, you can ignore all the documentation about the script being reviewed, approved, and sensitive and restricted scopes.  This is something that someone in your organization should learn how to do anyway.

Comment: Hi Alan, 
Thank you very much, I will look into it and implement it.